# Async python methods not executing as I need

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

Here is a simplified example of what my code is doing:

```
import asyncio
import time
import pandas as pd


async def execute_check():
    print("execute_check")
    items = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    tasks = [fetch_values_and_process(item) for item in items]
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


async def fetch_values_and_process(item):
    print("fetch_values_and_process")
    values_df = await fetch_values(item)

    a_values = values_df[values_df["Label"] == "A"]
    other_values = values_df[values_df["Label"] != "A"]

    if not a_values.empty:
        a_tasks = [a_task(row) for _, row in a_values.iterrows()]
        await asyncio.gather(*a_tasks)

    await other_task(other_values)


async def fetch_values(item):
    print("fetch_values")
    time.sleep(5)
    return pd.DataFrame({"Item": [1, 2, 3, 4], "Label": ["A", "B", "C", "D"]})


async def a_task(row):
    time.sleep(2)
    print("a_task")
    pass


async def other_task(other_values):
    time.sleep(2)
    print("other_task")
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(execute_check())
```

But it is not producing the behaviour I need. The output is:

```
fetch_values_and_process
fetch_values
fetch_values_and_process
fetch_values
fetch_values_and_process
fetch_values
fetch_values_and_process
fetch_values
a_task
a_task
a_task
a_task
other_task
other_task
other_task
other_task
```

But what I need is that `a_task` starts for each item once the data is loaded in `fetch_values`. i.e. Each item is independent and can run concurrently. Both `a_task` and `other_task` depend on the values being loaded by `fetch_values` and finally `other_task` can only be done once `a_task` is complete for that item.

This is my first time using async so I know it is a gap in my understanding :)

Comment: It looks like the tasks are already running concurrently. Otherwise the output would be: `fetch_values_and_process, fetch_values, a_task, other_task; fetch_values_and_process, fetch_values, a_task, other_task, ...`

Comment: Why does it appear to wait until all fetch_values and fetch_values_and_process are complete and then execute all of the a_task calls? I'd expect it can move on to a_task for the first fetch_values at some point before.

Answer (score 0):

you need to make sure that the fetch_values function is awaited for each item before proceeding with the processing tasks.

```
import asyncio
import time
import pandas as pd


async def execute_check():
    print("execute_check")
    items = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    tasks = [fetch_values_and_process(item) for item in items]
     await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


async def fetch_values_and_process(item):
  print(f"fetch_values_and_process for item {item}")
  values_df = await fetch_values(item)

  a_values = values_df[values_df["Label"] == "A"]
  other_values = values_df[values_df["Label"] != "A"]

  a_tasks = [a_task(row) for _, row in a_values.iterrows()]
  await asyncio.gather(*a_tasks)

   await other_task(other_values)


 async def fetch_values(item):
    print(f"fetch_values for item {item}")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)  # Use asyncio.sleep instead of time.sleep
    return pd.DataFrame({"Item": [item]*4, "Label": ["A", "B", "C", "D"]})


async def a_task(row):
   print("a_task")
   await asyncio.sleep(2)  # Use asyncio.sleep instead of time.sleep


 async def other_task(other_values):
   print("other_task")
   await asyncio.sleep(2)  # Use asyncio.sleep instead of time.sleep


 if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(execute_check())
```

Comment: Is the key change that within fetch_values you are now awaiting asyncio.sleep() ? So that in my actual program I should await whatever long task if requesting data?

`async def fetch_values():    
data = await long_call
return data`